# Motivating topological proofs

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

Hi I'm working on Rudin's real analysis textbook and I motivate the proofs about topology using $R$ $R^2$ and $R^3$ in my mind but I know he proves it for $R^n$. Even though I know if it works for the latter it should work the former, I am wondering if I should totally forget about the geometric intuition and solely work with logic and definitions for proving things more accurately in my mind as well. Or does he also motivate them with the basic metric spaces and just generalizes it to $R^n$?

Comment: You might be interested in reading the preface to Visual Complex Analysis by Needham.  "Lockhart's Lament" is also good.

Comment: Many results about $\Bbb R^n$ hold for (1) all metric spaces, or (2) all complete metric spaces, or (3) all metric spaces in which closed bounded subsets are compact. But I endorse the A from Robert Israel. In topology I always try to think in pictures.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should definitely **not** forget about geometric intuition.  It is a very powerful tool, even in high dimensions.  $\mathbb R^n$ is much like $\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb R^3$, it just has a few extra dimensions thrown in.